# Deploying Jersey 1.3 Web Service on Weblogic 9.2 or 10.1

Tags: java, tomcat, jaxb, weblogic, jersey

I am having issues deploying my Jersey RESTful web service to weblogic 9.2

I followed a tutorial at http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html.

The tutorial is for java 6 and tomcat 6 which it works fine for. However, I need to convert this to java 5 and tomcat 5.5 so that I can successfully deploy it on weblogic which uses java 1.5

When I use jre 5 and build the project, I get the following stack: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file (unable to load class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1884)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    ... 6 more`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I had to get the jersey jars for java 1.5 I downloaded the jersey 1.1.x jars and it worked fine.